# Recursively multiply elements in array using a for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, recursion

I am writing a program that will multiply the elements in a 2D array with elements in the following rows. I have a recursive method that first iterates through every row of the 2D array, finds where there is an array value other than 0, and then takes that value and multiplies it with the recursive call to run the function on the next row of the array. 
The problem is that the value from the recursion is returning before the for loop has a chance to move to the next element in the row. I know that this is a result from placing the `return` statement before the recursive call. But if I take out `return`, then the the integer returned from `total()` is really off (usually a 0).

```
int total(int current, int totalCont, int array[10][10]){

  //find the elements in the array that do not contain 0                      
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
   if(array[current][i] != 0){

      //base case                                                                              
      if(i == 0){
        return array[current][i];
      }

      //recursive case                                                                         
      else{
        return (array[current][i]) * (total(current+1, totalCont, array));

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case function will return the value right after the condition

```
    if(array[current][i] != 0)
```

is true.
So the value will be computed for the first column, such that

```
    array[current][column] != 0
```

But I don't clearly get the idea of your algorithm.

Also I see, that there is no exit point in recursion when function gets out of bounds by rows.
You should also add a condition, in this case like

```
    if (current >= 10) return something;
```

It will be useful to see more details of idea of the algorithm, which is not clear enough for me (maybe, I just don't see something).

Comment: In my algorithm, there are a few elements that I am not multiplying together and if there is an element that happens to have an integer other than 0 and appears when i==0, this returns as the base case. I don't think this affects the problem with the for loop not moving to the next element in a row after a number other than 0 is found.

Comment: You have recursion only by rows.
Algorithm just can't move anywhere further after element in row != 0 because it just returns value in this case.
But I actually really don't get, what result of function call you're expecting .